# Is there a known issue with internet explorer/IE11 not handling shinyjs/jquery?

Tags: jquery, r, internet-explorer, shiny, shinyjs

I have a Shiny app hosted on Shiny Server and nginx. I'm using action buttons and shinyjs to toggle elements based on ID. My app works without issue on every other major browser: Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari (I haven't tested Opera yet). It also works on these browsers on multiple operating systems: Win 7, Win 10, Android, iPhone, Ubuntu 18.04. However, Internet Explorer is a bust. I've only tried IE11, but I'm doubtful another version would work. The website loads just fine, but the buttons aren't reactive.

I'm not sure what to do to test this. I've used IE's element inspector and it recognizes the button as an event handler and cites the jquery file that's automatically generated by Shiny. That's what led me to my question: is this a specific compatibility issue with Internet Explorer and Shiny, or am I doing something wrong with my shinyjs code?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library("shinyjs")
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")

ui <- fluidPage(
    # welcome row ----
    fluidRow(id = "welcome",
             column(12,
                    h2(class = "display-4",
                       "Super Survey"),
                    p("Thank you for participating in this survey!"
                    ),

                    hr(class = "my-4"),
                    p("Click 'Next' to get started"),
                    p(class = "lead",
                        actionButton(class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
                                     "welcomenext",
                                     "Next")
                    )
             )),
    useShinyjs(),
    # questions row ----
    fluidRow(id = "questions",
             column(class = "card bg-light mb-3 px-0",
                 8,
                 div(id = "location",
                     div(class = "card-header text-white bg-dark",
                         h2(class="text-center",
                            "Where you're located")
                     ),
                     div(class = "card-body",
                         p(class="card-text",
                           "Tell us where you are!."
                         ),
                         # Input: Your Location ----
                         radioButtons(
                             inputId = "locationSelect",
                             "Select your location",
                             c("Location A", "Location B", "Location C"),
                             selected = character(0)
                         ),
                         actionButton(class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg", "locationnext", "Next")
                     )
                 ), # location section end
                 useShinyjs(),
                 div(id = "theQuestions",
                     # Input: Question1 ----
                     radioButtons(
                         inputId = "color",
                         "What's your favorite color?",
                         c("Red", "Blue", "Perriwinkle"),
                         selected = character(0)
                     ),
                     actionButton(class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg", "submit", "Submit")
                 ) %>% shinyjs::hidden() # theQuestions section end
             ) # col 8 inside questions row end
    ) %>% shinyjs::hidden(), # questions row end
    fluidRow(id = "theEnd",
             p("The end")
    ) %>% shinyjs::hidden() # theEnd row end
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    # Hide section when next button clicked, show next section ----
    observeEvent(input$welcomenext, {
        shinyjs::hide("welcome")
        shinyjs::toggle("questions")
    })
    observeEvent(input$locationnext, {
        shinyjs::toggle("location")
        toggle("theQuestions")
        # runjs("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")
    })
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
        shinyjs::toggle("questions")
        toggle("theEnd")
        runjs("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")
    })

    # Disable button if input missing ----
    observe({
        if (is.null(input$locationSelect) || input$locationSelect == "") {
            shinyjs::disable("locationnext")
        } else {
            shinyjs::enable("locationnext")
        }
    })

    observe({
        if (is.null(input$color) || input$color == "") {
            shinyjs::disable("submit")
        } else {
            shinyjs::enable("submit")
        }
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I expect is for the current section to hide and new sections to become visible when a button is clicked. Also, the buttons should be disabled if no input has been selected. Using Internet Explorer, I can't even get past the first "Next" button.

---

EDIT: Package versions: shinyjs 1.0, shinydashboard 0.7.1, shiny 1.3.2. Also, I just re-tested on my work machine and have the same issue- it works fine in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer.

---

EDIT 2: Figured it out. For some of my action buttons, it seems I incorrectly included type="button". It should be something like this:

```
actionButton(class="btn-lg", "submit", "Submit")
```

Instead, I had something like this:

```
actionButton(type="button", class="btn-lg", "submit", "Submit")
```

Comment: Can you please inform us, which version of ShinyJS you are using for making this test? I noticed, with some older versions of ShinyJS are not working properly with IE. If you are using any older version of ShinyJS than you can try to update it with the latest version to check whether it helps to solve this issue or not. It is also recommend to take a suggestions from official ShinyJS support may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I have tried your code with IE and it is perfectly working fine for me. You can update the ShinyJS Package what @Deepak-MSFT said.

Comment: It looks like I'm already using the most current versions of the shiny and shinyjs packages. What's weird is I also have a leaflet map on my actual Shiny app and that renders and reacts just fine in Internet Explorer, which relies on JavaScript but not shinyjs. What else can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: I suggest you to check with the official ShinyJS support because from IE side, we don't have any information available for any known issues for shinyJS app.